# Collection_select issue when collection objects are simple

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using RoR and I have a StateCity object which has 2 variables, state and city.  In my for I have this piece of code.

```
<%= collection_select( :state_city , :state , 
                          us_states , :id , :state_abbrev ) %>
```

And my collection is provided by an array in the helper like this.

```
def us_states
[
    {'state_name' => 'Alabama', 'state_abbrev' => 'AL'},
    ....
]
```

Now the collection_set method requires a value_method, but if you see the us_states, you can tell I don't really need full blown model. It doesn't feel right adding a low usage class to the application just so states can be selected.

P.S.  I am doing all of this with the collection_select because I want my form to have the state of the StateCity model already selected when the user is editing.  If anyone thinks I am going down the wrong path, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do this.

```
    <%= form_for (@state_city) do |s| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= s.label :city %><br />
        <%= s.text_field :city %>
       </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= s.label "State" %><br />
        <%= select_tag("state", options_for_select(us_states ,@state_city.state )) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```